# how you scale transaction queries

Tags: sql, node.js, pg

maybe wrong section idk, but how you deal when you having 20-50k concurrent querys with transactions ? what do I have to consider

Comment: I don't really get the question. Could you provide some examples or describe the detailed problem?

Comment: You need to share more details but you can look for connection pooling and also how to optimize the queries (if the last are being slow).

Comment: thanks both for your comment but I havent an example I have read a comment who anyone said that transaction scales not well so I asked this question to get information about what should I consider and what should I optimize

Comment: If you want 20-25K queries update the same row sure it will not scale well anyway.

Comment: @Serg and how big companies or ecommerce shop handle this ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs - may be of interest to you